# Parse.com show progress dialog on loading

Tags: android, gridview, progress-bar, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com and I'm trying to show a progress while the data loads into my gridview. Check out my attempt below. The progress bar never show up. It just show a white screen then starts showing gridview items.

rListActivity.java

```
public class rListActivity extends Activity {
    pAdapter padapter;
    GridView gridview;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
        gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        padapter = new pAdapter(this);
         padapter.loadObjects();
        padapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(new ParseQueryAdapter.OnQueryLoadListener<Meal>() {

            @Override
            public void onLoading() {
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(rListActivity.this);
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                mProgressDialog.show();

            }


            @Override
            public void onLoaded(List<Meal> objects, Exception e) {
                gridview.setAdapter(padapter);
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


    }
```

pAdapter.java

```
    public class pAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<Meal> {

        public pAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Meal>() {
                public ParseQuery<Meal> create() {

                    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Meal");

                    query.orderByAscending("title");
                    return query;
                }
            });

        }
......

Itemviews....
```

Comment: This might be clutching at straws but in rListActivity.java have you tried putting your call padapter.loadObjects() after you add the listener?

Comment: Hi marcus, I've just debugged it. It seems it wouldn't run the addOnQueryLoadListener. What did I do wrong?

Comment: It looks like this might be a [bug](https://www.parse.com/questions/androidparsequeryadapter-onqueryloadlistener-onloading-not-getting-called) parse API.

Comment: Sigh, just wasted all my time learning Parse and all I end up with is some bugs. Thanks marcus.

Comment: Are you using 1.4? It looks like they just did a new release of the SDK in the new year. Maybe it got fixed there.

Comment: Hi marcus, I'm using 1.4. droidx, I've tried that, it doesnt work.

Comment: There is still a bug with this even on version 1.9.2. If you try to add progressDialog to onLoading() addOnQueryLoadListener will not get called

Comment: have you solved your problem? i am also facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late but the answer is very easy.

You need to call `padapter.loadObjects();` after

```
padapter.addOnQueryLoadListener(new ParseQueryAdapter.OnQueryLoadListener<Meal>() {

        @Override
        public void onLoading() {
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(rListActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();

        }


        @Override
        public void onLoaded(List<Meal> objects, Exception e) {
            gridview.setAdapter(padapter);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```